# Get Plain Text List of Top '#x' Search Terms

Tags: http, search, post

Is there a place I can find the top x number of search terms (preferably from Google) and import them via something such as a HTTP Request/Post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you'll need to use [Google's Custom Search API.](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)  Specifically, you can use the [num parameter](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list) to tell it how many results to return.  Also, items[].title will give you the title in plain text, items[].snippet will give you the snippet in plain text.